# Prove that endomorphism $\phi$ is injective iff $ 0 \notin Sp(\phi)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that endomorphism $\phi$ is injective iff $ 0 \notin Sp(\phi).$

$\Rightarrow$

Let's assume $0 \in Sp(\phi)$. 
From the definion of spectrum, there is non-zero vector for which $$\phi(v) = 0 * v = 0$$ But $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi$ is injective, so contradiction as $v$ is non-zero, and so: $$0 \notin Sp(\phi).$$

$\Leftarrow$

I have no idea. From assumption I know that $$\phi(v) \neq 0 \iff v\neq 0 $$
so only zero vector is equal to 0. How does this imply injectiveness?

Comment: $\phi(u)=\phi(u')\Leftrightarrow \phi(u-u')=\phi(u)-\phi(u')=0\Leftrightarrow u-u'=0\Leftrightarrow u=u'$.

Comment: Where do you use the fact that $0 \notin Sp(\phi)$?

Comment: I did'nt, you did. I just showed you how your last equation imply injectiveness.

Comment: I don't understand, I'll ask other way: what part of your proof wouldn't hold, if we didn't assume that?

Comment: The second equivalence would be wrong. It's precisely what you've written if you take $v=u-u'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi$ were injective, then there would have to be distinct $v,v'$ for which $\phi(v)=\phi(v')$. If $w=v-v'$, then we now have $\phi(w)=0$. So, $w$ is an eigenvector of $\phi$ for the eigenvalue $0$.